# oEmbed provider servlet to handle four media types

Tags: java, object-oriented, api, servlets

I would like to add oEmbed tags to my site (I'm the oEmbed api provider). My api should respond the results based on the file type.

oEmbed Types has

- Photo
- Video
- Link
- Rich

My response to **photo** contains the following field

```
{
    "author_name": "meera.s",
    "author_url": <author_image_url>,
    "thumbnail_width": 130,
    "provider_url": <provider_url>,
    "thumbnail_url": "<thumbnail_image_url>",
    "title": "Picture.png",
    "provider_name": "XYZ",
    "type": "photo",
    "version": "1.0",
    "url": "<given_url>",
    "thumbnail_height": 120
}
```

My response to **video** contains the following field

```
{
    "author_name": "meera.s ",
    "author_url": "<image_url_of_author>",
    "thumbnail_width": 130,
    "html": "<iframe src="<source_url>" width=\"480\" height=\"270\" frameborder=\"0\">",
    "provider_url": "<service_url>",
    "thumbnail_url": "<thumbnail_image_url>",
    "title": "video_small_resource.mp4",
    "provider_name": "XYZ",
    "type": "video",
    "version": "1.0",
    "thumbnail_height": 120
}
```

And similarly for **link** and **rich** types.

I’m implementing this api in the following way. All I have is a servlet (where the api request lands). Here I have the following

```
public class OEmbedServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
    {
        //Parse request uri

        String format = request.getParameter(“format”);
        String url = request.getParameter(“url”);
        String file_id = request.getParameter(“file_id”);

        String max_width = request.getParameter(“max_height”);
        String max_height = request.getParameter(“max_width”);

        if(authorised_user) {
            oembed.setFileInfo(file_id);
            oembed.setProviderInfo();
            oembed.setURL(url);
            oembed.setThumbnailInfo();
            oembed.setOEmbedType();
        }

        writeResponse(response, oembed.getJSONObject(), format);
   }
}
```

And another class which does all utility job for this servlet

```
public class OEmbed {
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    public OEmbed(HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
        this.oembedType = OEmbedType.LINK;
        this.width = 0;
        this.height = 0;
        this.thumbnailWidth = 0;
        this.thumbnailHeight = 0;
    }

    public enum OEmbedType {
        RICH/*0*/,
        LINK/*1*/,
        PHOTO/*2*/,
        VIDEO/*3*/
    }

    public void String author;
    public void String file_id;
    public void String extension;
    public void String fileType;

    //Getter and setter methods for all required info to be passed in the response like 

    public String getAuthorName() {
        return this.author;
    }

    public String setAuthorName(String name) {
        this.author = name;
    }

    public void setURL(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getURL(String url) {
        return this.url;
    }

    //…. and other getter and setter methods
    /*
    - Few setter methods are invoked from the servlet
    - Few setter methods are clubbed together and invoked from util classes
    - The setter methods in util does some computation to assign value - or they are assigned based on inputted params
    - All required getter methods are obtained while writing response json
    */

    public JSONObject getJSONObject(boolean isAuthorised) throws Exception
    {
        JSONObject oembedObj = new JSONObject();
        if(this.url != null && !this.url.isEmpty()) {
            switch(this.oembedType) {
                case PHOTO:
                oembedObj.put("url", this.thumbnailUrl);
                break;
                case LINK:
                oembedObj.put("url", this.url);
                default:
                oembedObj.put("url", this.url);
                oembedObj.put("html", htmlContent);
                break;
            }
        }

        if(this.thumbnailUrl != null && !this.thumbnailUrl.isEmpty()) {
            oembedObj.put(“thumbnail_url”, this.thumbnailUrl);
            oembedObj.put(“thumbnail_width”, this.thumbnailWidth);
            oembedObj.put(“thumbnail_height”, this.thumbnailHeight);
        }

    }
}
```

I still feel this design very cumbersome. I feel inconvenient in the following things,

- few setter methods were invoked from servlet and few were invoked from util class
- also while making use of class variables in util class - i have to be careful whether those attribute values were already initialised

say for an example

```
public void setThubnailUrl(String url) {
this.thumbnail_url = url;
}
public void setThubnailUrl() {
setThumbnailInfo();
getThumbnailType();
setThumbnailUrl(url);    //So before initialising this url - i have to make sure manually - whether the required params for thumbnail url is initialised already (I'm not sure weather it is a best practice to do like this)
}
```

How can I organise it in a much better way? Which design pattern would be appropriate?